# Subtracting two arrays using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I've two arrays *arr1* and *arr2* of the following type

```
class Data
{
  public int IdProduct;
  public double Price;
}
```

and I need to subtract the Price of *arr2* to *arr1* but the items of the arrays are the result of different queries so **the amount of products in *arr1* not necessarily match the amount of products in *arr2* and there're no duplicated products in the arrays.**

I need to do the subtraction product by product in each array, ie.

```
var total =
  from a1 in arr1
  join a2 in arr2 on a1.IdProducto equals a2.IdProducto
  select new
  {
    Product = a1.IdProduct,
    Price = a1.Price - a2.Price
  };
```

Comment: What dou you exactly mean? ( Sum of arr2 ) - ( Sum of arr1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var q = from a in arr1
                  join b in arr2 on a.IdProduct equals b.IdProduct into c
              from x in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new Data {
                IdProduct = a.IdProduct,
                Price = x == null ? a.Price : a.Price - x.Price
              };

arr1 = q.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = arr1.Concat(arr2)
            .GroupBy(d => d.IdProduct)
            .Select(x => new Data
            {
                IdProduct = x.Key,
                Price = x.Select((y,i) => i == 0 ? y.Price : -y.Price).Sum()
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two arrays of `Data` with a *total price difference*?

```
arr1.Sum(d => d.Price) - arr2.Sum(d => d.Price);
```

Basically this code *sums up both arrays* and subtracts afterwards. The total effort is therefore *linearly growing* with the length of the arrays: `O(n+m)`.